# Nougat getUriForFile issue with camera Return

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat

I've been trying to update my app to the way Nougat handles URI in intents and can't for the life of me figure out how to get the camera to work again. I've tried following the documentation but I must be missing something. Can anyone help?

this is my dispatch event

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            return;
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                   "com.everywhere_ww.provider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

this is my provider in manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.everywhere_ww.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

This is my file paths

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="imgFolder" path="pictures" />
<external-path name="tempFolder" path="temp" />
```

Attempting to take a picture always fails with a

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.everywhere_ww/files/temp/JPEG_20170223_101548_1550424251.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/data/data/com.everywhere_ww/files/temp/JPEG_20170223_101548_1550424251.jpg` would appear to be a path pointing to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). You created this via `getFilesDir()`, presumably.

Replace:

```
<external-path name="tempFolder" path="temp" />
```

with:

```
<files-path name="tempFolder" path="temp" />
```

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare! That was exactly the problem, that's also a very helpful link explaining the androids weird storage nomenclature. Great help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi not sure can make the difference but try to add to your xml file paths the following param

```
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
```